# PHP String in Array returns only first charachter

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php function to display a list of revslider's sliders (wp plugin), the string returns only the first letter of the sliders' names 
here is my code :

```
function jobboard_revslider(){

    if (class_exists('RevSlider')) {
        $theslider     = new RevSlider();
        $arrSliders = $theslider->getArrSliders();
        $arrA     = array();
        $arrT     = array();
        foreach($arrSliders as $slider){
            $arrA[]     = $slider->getAlias();
            $arrT[]    = $slider->getTitle();
        }
        if($arrA && $arrT){
            $result = array_combine($arrA, $arrT);
        }
        else
        {
            $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

I tried all I know and other answers around here but no hope.
I would really appreciate a push !
Thanks

Comment: Not the `if` inside `foreach` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check sizeof ($ array)> 0 do this for both arrays. Also just try to echo what you are getting in getalias and gettitle methods before storing it in array.

Answer (score 0):

function jobboard_revslider(){

```
if (class_exists('RevSlider')) {
    $theslider     = new RevSlider();
    $arrSliders = $theslider->getArrSliders();
    $arrA     = array();
    $arrT     = array();
    foreach($arrSliders as $slider){
        $arrA[]    = substr($slider->getAlias(), 1);
        $arrT[]    = substr($slider->getTitle(), 1);
    }
    if($arrA && $arrT){
        $result = array_combine($arrA, $arrT);
    }
    else
    {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Try using substr to the return value of the slider, then put in on array see if that works.